# How to make iOS UIToolbar with back/forward arrows on the left

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

I am trying to place a toolbar above a date picker that has back and forward arrows on the left side of the toolbar.  I'd like to do this using standard iOS machinery and not roll out custom buttons to do this.  Is this possible?  I have attached an image for referral.  Thanks in advance!

[image: Example toolbar with desired <> assets]

Comment: have you made any headway on this problem.  I am running into the same thing.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with? Making a bar button item that looks like those arrows? getting the arrows to be on the left side of the toolbar? Make the toolbar appear above your date picker? You're question is not very specific.

Answer (score 14):

I know you don't want to use custom buttons, and this solution doesn't have custom buttons, but it does have custom icons.  I hope it works for you.  I have looked all over the place for a solution and did not find anything that Apple built, so I figured I would make my own.  This is what it looks like, not identical, but pretty close.

[image]

In my method where I make the toolbar, I used this code.

```
 previousButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Back.png"]
                                                      style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                                     target:self 
                                                     action:@selector(previousField:)];
 nextButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Forward.png"]
                                                  style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                                 target:self 
                                                 action:@selector(nextField:)];
```

All you need to do is insert the images.  I made both retina and non retina in a program called Paint Code.

Maybe this will help someone out.

EDIT 7/16/17
Added the 3x images as well!

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Needs 3x next :)

Comment: @aehlke, here you go!!

Comment: Thanks - the new ones have a white BG though

Comment: @aehlke. Ok. I'll see if I can change them this week. I must have forgotten to export them w/o the BK!

Comment: @aehlke, I didn't have time for both, but I think the one I included is more like the one used by Apple.  And no white background!