# Buttons on the Safari browser toolbar

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, uibutton, uibarbuttonitem

Are the back and forward buttons on the Safari browser available to use on iOS? I have been looking in the `UIButton` and `UIBarbuttonItem` class and I don't see those icons under these classes. Can someone tell me if they are available or is the browser using custom icons?

Here is how the back and forward button look on the browser [image: Browser]

Answer (score 1):

Check out my answer to this at [How to make iOS UIToolbar with back/forward arrows on the left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19058654/how-to-make-ios-uitoolbar-with-back-forward-arrows-on-the-left/20407574#20407574).  I made them myself because they are not included as you have found out.  I made them in [Paint Code](http://www.paintcodeapp.com).

Answer (score 0):

If you are targeting iOS13 and above, you can use the built-in `SF Symbols` library provided by Apple.

The `chevron.left` image is used for the Safari back button.

```
let chevronLeft = UIImage(systemName: "chevron.left")
let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: chevronLeft, style: .plain, target: webView, action: #selector(webView!.goBack))
```

These icons also come in nine weights from ultralight to black, which can be applied like this.

```
let chevronLeft = UIImage(systemName: "chevron.left", withConfiguration: UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(weight: .thin))
```

More information is available from Apple here: [SF Symbols](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/sf-symbols/overview/)